# Documentation about difference between javascript src and javascript library in grails

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I know that if you write in a view:

```
<g:javascript src="myscript.js" />
<g:javascript src="myscript.js" />
<g:javascript src="myscript.js" />

<!-- other try -->
<g:javascript library="myscript" />
<g:javascript library="myscript" />
<g:javascript library="myscript" />
```

It will out output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vip/js/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vip/js/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vip/js/myscript.js"></script>

<!-- other try -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vip/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Conclution: with library it will try to include only once.

I have been try to find documentation about it without success.

Do you have any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Source Code

Check out the Documentation ([http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html#)) then click `Show Source` you will see the code is only going to output the first time

`if(!request[INCLUDED_LIBRARIES].contains(attrs.library)) {`

Hope this helps.